# MaaS dhcp cannot be detected at node installation

Tags: networking, dns, maas, dhcp

I am installing a MaaS Ubuntu 12.04 by ISO with virtualbox as the host machine.

I have a problem on the cluster management during the process of adding the node. 
The node cannot detect the dhcp configuration from the MaaS host machine during installation.

I have even started off the managed DHCP & DNS at the host MaaS WebUI to the interface pointing to the node VM.

I am not sure if I need to install dhcpd, as the MaaS already provides maas-dhcp and maas-dns.

How can I check to see if maas-dhcp and mass-dns is working correctly?

Comment: Are you adding servers with the add server button in the UI or are you having the servers PXE boot to add them? By "annot detect the dhcp configuration" do you mean it doesn't get an address and times out, or that it gives you some error when it is installing and can't find a config file? Are the servers you are adding physical or another Virtual machine? What are the network settings you have set in virtualbox?

Comment: You need to have installed it like this "sudo apt-get install maas maas-dhcp".  But you can do a "ps -aux | grep dhcp" to see if there is a service running.